# PowerBI Query WebMethod.Post returns Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "POST" to type Function

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, webmethod

I'm using a website that *requires* that their API key AND query data be submitted using Webform.Post method. I'm able to get this to work in Python, C# and I'm even able to construct and execute a cURL command which returns a usable JSON file that Excel can parse. I am also using Postman to validate my parameters and everything looks good using all these methods. However, my goal is to build a query form that I can use within Excel but I can't get past this query syntax in PowerBi Query.

For now I am doing a simple query. That query looks like this:

```js
let
    url_1 = "https://api.[SomeWebSite].com/api/v1.0/search/keyword?apiKey=blah-blah-blah",

    Body_1 = {
            
            "SearchByKeywordRequest: 
            
            {
                ""keyword"": ""Hex Nuts"",
                ""records"": 0,
                ""startingRecord"": 0,
                ""searchOptions"": Null.Type,
                ""searchWithYourSignUpLanguage"": Null.Type
            }"
            
             },
    
    Source = WebMethod.Post(url_1,Body_1)
    
in
    Source
```

[ScreenSnip showing valid syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKoHr.png)

It generates the following error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "POST" to type Function.
Details:
    Value=POST
    Type=[Type]
```

[ScreenSnip of Error as it appears in PowerQuery Advanced Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNztE.png)

I've spend the better part of the last two days trying to find either some example using this method or documentation. The Microsoft documentation simple states the follow:

```
WebMethod.Post
04/15/2018
2 minutes to read

About
Specifies the POST method for HTTP.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/webmethod-post

This is of no help and the only posts I have found so far criticize the poster for not using GET versus POST. I would do this but it is **NOT** supported by the website I'm using. If someone could just please either point me to a document which explains what I am doing wrong or suggest a solution, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

`WebMethod.Post` is not a function. It is a constant text value "POST". You can send POST request with either `Web.Contents` or `WebAction.Request` function.

A simple example that posts JSON and receives JSON:

```
let
    url = "https://example.com/api/v1.0/some-resource-path",
    headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/json"],
    body = Json.FromValue([Foo = 123]),
    source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers = headers, Content = body])),
    ...
```

#### Added Nov 14, 19

Request body needs to be a binary type, and included as `Content` field of the second parameter of `Web.Contents` function.

You can construct a binary JSON value using `Json.FromValue` function. Conversely, you can convert a binary JSON value to a corresponding M type using `Json.Document` function.

Note `{}` is *list* type in M language, which is similar to JSON array. `[]` is *record* type, which is similar to JSON object.

With that said, your query should be something like this,

```
let
    url_1 = "https://api.[SomeWebSite].com/api/v1.0/search/keyword?apiKey=blah-blah-blah",

    Body_1 = Json.FromValue([
        SearchByKeywordRequest = [
            keyword = "Hex Nuts",
            records = 0,
            startingRecord = 0,
            searchOptions = null,
            searchWithYourSignUpLanguage = null
        ]
    ]),

    headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/json"],

    source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url_1, [Headers = headers, Content = Body_1])),

    ...
```

References:

- Web.Contents (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents)
- Json.FromValue (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/json-fromvalue)
- Json.Document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/json-document)

Comment: Thank you for replying. However, I am unable to understand the example as stated. So let me rephrase it another way. How to I get this Body_1 = {
            
            "SearchByKeywordRequest: 
            
            {
                ""keyword"": ""Hex Nuts"",
                ""records"": 0,
                ""startingRecord"": 0,
                ""searchOptions"": Null.Type,
                ""searchWithYourSignUpLanguage"": Null.Type
            }"
            
             },