# Using Post in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery

I have used Postman for my POST query and was able to use body (raw) to pass my parameters.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n1Bo.png)

How do I do that in PowerQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use `Web.Contents` function.

Please see this.

[PowerBI Query WebMethod.Post returns Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "POST" to type Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58794715/powerbi-query-webmethod-post-returns-expression-error-we-cannot-convert-the-val/58795671#58795671)